# With which character or token can a .java source file start with?

Tags: java, java-7

I could come up with the following ways to start a `.java` file (each line is a separate `.java` file):

```
package p; class fa {}
import java.net.URL; class fb { URL u; }
class fc {}
interface fd {}
enum fe {}
@Deprecated class ff {}
/**/ class fg {}
\u0063lass fh {}
abstract class fi {}
final class fj {}
public class fk {}
;class fl {}
strictfp class fm {}
```

In addition to the the files above, the empty file and the file containing only an ASCII SUB (decimal 26) character also compiles.

Are there any others I've missed?

Please ignore whitespace in the beginning. If it doesn't start with an ASCII letter, only the first character counts (e.g. no need to mention `//` because we've already mentioned `/*`), otherwise the first word counts.

Comment: Abstract / public / private

Comment: But why is this important?

Comment: Can't java classes be abstract, or have the usual accessor modifiers (public, private, default, protected..)?

Comment: FYI `protected`, `private` and `static` are allowed only for inner classes. I've just added `abstract`, `final` and `public`, because they work.

Comment: @vikingsteve: This can be important for writing multilingual programs, i.e. such source files which compile in multiple languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of expected tokens is

```
Sub WhiteSpace Comment EOF ';' '@' 'abstract' 'class' 'enum' 'final' 'import'
'interface' 'native' 'package' 'private' 'protected' 'public' 'static' 
'strictfp' 'synchronized' 'transient' 'volatile'
```

It can be found as follows:

- download the [Java 7 grammar](http://bottlecaps.de/rex/Java.ebnf) for [REx parser generator](http://bottlecaps.de/rex), which was made from the [JLS (Java SE 7 Edition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)
- generate a parser for it, e.g. using command line `-ll 2 -backtrack -java -tree -main`
- in the generated code, find the initial lexer call for the start symbol, in method `parse_Input`. It it is annotated with exactly the tokens that are expected at the start of a Java 7 source file.

That code looks like this:

```
lookahead1W(90);                // Sub | WhiteSpace | Comment | EOF | ';' | '@' | 'abstract' | 'class' | 'enum' |
                                // 'final' | 'import' | 'interface' | 'native' | 'package' | 'private' |
                                // 'protected' | 'public' | 'static' | 'strictfp' | 'synchronized' | 'transient' |
                                // 'volatile'
```

Comment: What does Sub mean? What would be the first word for Sub?

Comment: Of the tokens mentioned in this answer but not in the question, only `strictfp` and `;` work, the others cause a compile error (other than a parse error), e.g. `native class C {}` doesn't compile. I've updated the question to include the new ones which work.

Comment: I like this answer, because it explains why other tokens are not possible.

Comment: @pts, I agree on `native`. Though the syntax definition allows it, along with all other `Modifier`s, it will be rejected by a semantics check. So this shows that the syntactic approach only delivers a superset of the tokens starting a valid Java file. `Sub` is specified like this: `As a special concession for compatibility with certain operating systems, the ASCII SUB character (\u001a, or control-Z) is ignored if it is the last character in the escaped input stream.` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5-140 )

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I've added Sub to the question.

Answer (score 3):

For a comprehensive description, see [the grammar definition of `CompilationUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3) and [the lexical structure of Java programs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) in the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

**final / abstract** class ClassName ..